# Hibernate first level cache and get method

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I have read that the `session.get(Employee.class, new Long(1))` method will take the data from cache or database.

If there are two users who are accessing the application concurrently.

if user - > User1 is doing get then data will be retrieved from DB. Now data is moved to cache.
If user - > User2 has deleted the record or updated the record. then
If user - > User1 is doing get then data will it be retrieved from cache.

Isnt User1 is getting old data. Does it falls to pitfall of caching.
Or am I missing something here?

I can say on this that why User1 is doing 2 times `session.get` in the same session. But still I need different opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You understand it correctly: the cache is bound to the session, and if an object is loaded into the first-level cache, then no SQL will executed with `#get()`. You could use `#evict()` to clear one object from the cache, or `#clear()` to clear every object from the cache, without closing the session. Closing the session will always delete the entire cache.

See a nice explanation [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/understanding-hibernate-first-level-cache-with-example/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about **Container-managed entity manager**

> The most common and widely used entity manager in a Java EE
>   environment is the container-managed entity manager. In this mode, the
>   container is responsible for the opening and closing of the entity
>   manager (this is transparent to the application). It is also
>   responsible for transaction boundaries. A container-managed entity
>   manager is obtained in an application through dependency injection or
>   through JNDI lookup, A container-managed entity manger requires the
>   use of a JTA transaction.

It's responable of what do you want understand and archive and how is used it.
More doucmentation  [Entity Mananger](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/architecture.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, because Hibernate saves data on cache, but whether you update the data with Hibernate it will know that some change exists. You will have troubles if you update the data with SQL or from other point where Hibernate cannot see that something happends.

Comment: I think if you have two distinct session on two different machines with two distinct caches, and you update through one, the other's cache *will be outdated*, although "Hibernate know about it". Do I get something wrong?